# Will a VPN make a DNS Server more secure?

Tags: networking, router, security, dns

I have a DNS Server (unblock-us) at the router level to allow US Netflix for everyone on my home network.
I am concerned about all my traffic (eg internet banking) going through these servers and the potential for a MITM attack.
If I use a VPN (which in normal circumstances hides my traffic from my ISP) would this also hide my traffic from the DNS Server?

Comment: Netflix is actively blocking access to its services from VPN services.  Unless you are willing to rent your own VPS, and setup and host your own VPN Server, its very likely Netflix will eventually block you from accessing their services while connected to a commercial VPN service.  *It isn't clear why you are worried about MITM attacks, an identity cannot perform a MITM attack, without you knowing about it.*  You would be notified of a certificate problem when you view a website while under a MITM attack.

Answer (score 1):

A DNS server mainly translates domain names to IP addresses. Therefore, you only communicate with a DNS server for address resolution. None of your actual traffic passes through.

In your case, Unblock-us is actually a proxy.
It uses an additional DNS server to simplify the use of the proxy. Therefore, this DNS server decides what part of your internet traffic to pass through their proxy (this should be limited to only sites like Netflix etc, but it's up to them to change it).

Using a VPN in this case will (probably) have no effect. They *could* still perform a MITM attack by altering their DNS records.
Your computer (and VPN provider) will therefore think that Unblock-us' servers are the actual destination servers (eg the Bank's servers), and your traffic will be visible. (but you *should* be fine when using https)

Note: With the term VPN I assume a VPN connection between you and an intermediate server (that is not the destination, eg your Bank).

I would suggest using the Unblock-us' DNS servers only when needed (eg for Netflix) and changing them back to the defaults/ISP's otherwise.

Comment: Thanks for the above. Unfortunately with a spouse and 3 teenagers in the house we need netflix a lot of the time, hence using the DNS server/unblock us at the router level. I should have clarified that I only use the VPN for banking/purchases etc. I understand that it would be better to remove the DNS from the router but with so many devices is much easier to have it at that base level. So I suppose what I am really asking is are my data/IP addresses looked at/passwords hidden from unblock us/safe from MITM attack if I am using a VPN at those times I access those particular websites.

Comment: Well, in that case I can only think of the following tricks you could do.

Comment: 1) use the default DNS, and (for Netflix) the IP of Unblock-us directly instead of "netflix.com" (do a ping while using Unblock-us to find it)

2) set up a local DNS server, changing only the DNS entry for Netflix.com. You could use a raspberry pi here (google it).

Using their DNS all the time, as I mentioned in my answer, if they really wanted to intercept your data, they could do it (though not likely), unless I haven't understand what you mean with VPN.